# What is snap interaction in Openlayer3?

Tags: openlayers-3

technically what happens with snap interaction in openlayers.

referance http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/examples/snap.html

Answer (score 1):

From the API documentation of the Snap interaction:

> Handles snapping of vector features while modifying or drawing them.
>   The features can come from a ol.source.Vector or ol.Collection Any
>   interaction object that allows the user to interact with the features
>   using the mouse can benefit from the snapping, as long as it is added
>   before.
>
> The snap interaction modifies map browser event coordinate and pixel
>   properties to force the snap to occur to any interaction that them.

See: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/examples/snap.html

In other words, the Snap interaction listens to the browser events that occur on the map and modifies its inner coordinates to "snap" to the closest vertex or segment of a nearby feature. Any other interaction that are added to the map before a snap interaction will use the updated coordinates, because the "top-most, i.e. last" interactions are handled first.